Absolute R1 addressing for Google Sheets named range definition
Google Sheets, attempting to define multi-cell named 'constants.'
I have a list of items with attributes.  Some of the items have identical subsets of attributes, and I want to link those to a central definition, stored in a separate sheet.  However, the placement of the attribute list in the item sheet (row and column) does NOT match that of the master range in the definition sheet.
This would be instantly solved if a named range's value could use absolute addressing, so regardless of where the reference to the name occurred, row and column, on the item sheet, it would still refer to the absolute range in the definition sheet.  However, I can't seem to make named range definitions use absolute addressing.  Defining the range as defs!$C$23:$F$23 just results in the $s being elided altogether
For example, two sheets (defs and items):  Named range cap27 is defined as defs!C23:F23.  As long as a reference to =cap27 in the items sheet (in cells items!C199:F199) starts in column C, all is well.
However, putting =cap27 into items!D199:G199 applies weird relative interpretation resulting in off-by-one range indexing and a #VALUE! error in G199.
So, the simple question is:

Can a Google Sheets named range be defined using absolute addressing, or not?


Directly answering your question, it is not allowed, though there is no available document supporting this, Google Sheet explicitly removes "$" on the ranges thus implying my answers to your question. Though can you share a sample sheet highlighting you desired output, so the community will have better idea of what is happening and maybe give some ideas for a workaround or fixes.
